# Java Menu with Quantities

Tags: java, javafx

I have a menu receipt in a TextArea `txtReceipt` in Java FX. Any time a food item is clicked, the following code is executed where the name and cost are displayed.

```
@FXML
public void buttonHandler(ActionEvent event) {
    NumButton button = (NumButton) event.getSource();
    txtReceipt.appendText ((String) button.getText() + "\t" + "\t" + button.getCost() + "\n");
    total += button.getCost();
    numTotalAmt.setText(String.valueOf("$ " + total));
}
```

NumButton is simply a JavaFX button holding the cost and quantity value. I am a little stuck on how to handle the quantity value. So if someone clicks "Egg" twice, it will show up "`Egg   2    $6`".  However, my method `buttonHandler` will display them as two separate entries.

I have a good idea of how to accomplish my task but am looking for inputs for on how to accomplish it the most efficiently. I was thinking of throwing in a good old ArrayList where each food item is connected with a quantity which can be added upon then displayed. I do not feel this would be efficient for sorting through and possibly changing the cost or name of an item down the road (something I hope to get to). Any suggestions on what data structure to use here?

Comment: A receipt is generally generated at time of transaction. Why would the cost or name of an item change at the time of transaction? What is the use case for this?

Comment: You can just add a "+" button next to each button or however you want, Click on + to increment the number of items to buy, then click one time on the button to validate the number of items :p no need to sacrifice too much memory using an arrayList

Comment: This is a rolling receipt Eric, something the server sees. Thanks @Calips